# Setting a standard for user input

Tags: requirements

I have a project on a classified ad site, and my client wants a **QUALITY** requirement when users post.

It has 2 purposes:

1. To filter out **spam** and other useless stuff
2. To make sure that content posted has useful information, full of detail and stuff.

There are alternative classified ad sites without the **QUALITY** check just a minimum number of words. Will it be a problem? There is this concept of giving users as little work as possible. .

Comment: Is the question, how this can be achieved without much overhead?

Comment: more of a `Will it still be a good user experience even with the QUALITY check that has specific requirements to comply before proceeding to the next part`?

Comment: How do you define quality?

Answer (score 4):

The user experience *will* suffer if you make it a past-input check.

Users enter content, probably write a bunch of lines and get a message about how it isn't okay after they did all the work, this leads to a bad experience.

So you have to **display the potential errors on-the-fly**. Like *"Still 100 words to go"*

Also, you should consider **analyse what high quality *is***.

A generic text input field with *"write all your stuff here and let it be >500 words"* probably won't lead to good quality.

If you found out **what kind of informations are needed**, you can split it up in a few input fields with semantic differences, with each having some restrictions.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but there is a problem with the spam fighting part. Revealing what to do to get past the spam filter will indeed be more user friendly to the small number of users who get false positives for sending spam, but it will also render the spam filter useless.

Comment: yeah, that's why I said "analyse what high quality is". In some systems it is rather easy to analyse and implement plausibility checks. In others, like Stackexchange, it's complicated and has to be done by humans :\

Comment: I find the minimum words and QUALITY check approach to be bad since spammers just need to create one good post and spam away. I'm suggesting to my client to reduce spam, lock out the number of times users can post in a day lets say 10 is more than enough since the average normal user doesn't post that much ads in a day and if the content has similar records in the db tag it for moderator check. I need more reasons to change my clients mind on what to do :(

Comment: If you split up the input into the different details, which you said you want, this will probably allow for a better checking of the input data.